# Yii2: Convert hasMany() relation into hasOne()

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, yii2-active-records

I need to be able to convert a `hasMany()` relation, which queries and return an `array` into a `hasOne()` relation which returns `object|null`.

Use case:

```
public function getItems() : \yii\db\ActiveQuery {
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class, ['parent_id' => 'id']);
}
```

I want to create a relation which returns one specific `Item` object (or `null` if it does not exist).

I would like to do something like this:

```
public function getPrimaryItem() : \yii\db\ActiveQuery {
    return $this->getItems()->andWhere(["primary"=>true])->toHasOne();
}
```

Please do not tell me to call `->one()` on the original query, because that is not going to solve the problem. I need to be able to:

- call `$model->primaryItem` and receive either `Item` or `null`
- call `$model->getPrimaryItem()` and receive the relation's `ActiveQuery`

Comment: I didn't test it but there is a [`$multiple`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerelationtrait#$multiple-detail) property in `ActiveQuery` what about adding the where condition and changing that property to false?

Comment: @MichalHynčica I've actually done that and it seems to be working, but I am not sure if this approach will lead to any unpredictable pitfalls.

Comment: I don't think there will be any pitfall. Both `hasMany()` and `hasOne()` uses [`createRelationQuery()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/af29687f5f09759f682d33fde5baea44fe1c0e59/framework/db/BaseActiveRecord.php#L445) method with only difference being the `$multiple` property.

Comment: @MichalHynčica Isn't this going to also modify and break the original plural (`getItems()`) relation?

Comment: It shouldn't. Every time the `getItems()` or `getPrimaryItem()` is called the new instance of `ActiveQuery` is created. If you access `$model->items` or `$model->primaryItem` the results of query are stored in private `$_related` property, but they are stored with relation name as key: `$_related['items']` or `$_related['primaryItem']` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle it by `multiple` property of `\yii\db\ActiveQuery`

```
public function getPrimaryItem() : \yii\db\ActiveQuery {
    $query =  $this->getItems();
    $query->multiple = false;

    //Your logics
    $query->andWhere(["primary"=>true])

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change *hasMany* to *hasOne* call and then add *where* filter to query; it's to return the first row found then

```
public function getPrimaryItem() : \yii\db\ActiveQuery {
    return $this->hasOne(Item::class, ['parent_id' => 'id'])->where(["primary" => true]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**